# icons should hover in jQuery and transform in size with css animation

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("icon4").mouseover(function(){
    $("icon4").animate({height: "300px", width: "300px"});
    $("icon4").mouseout(function(){
      $("icon4").animate({height:"100px", width: "100px"});
      . . .
    });
  });
});

<p class = "icon4">
  <a href="https://github.com/jenniferobregon">
    <img src = "git.png">
  </a>
</p>
```

In the code above I am trying to make my icon increase in size when the mouse goes to hover over it and go back to original size when the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way.

```js
const toggleIcon = (e) => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
};

$('.icon').on('mouseover', toggleIcon);

$('.icon').on('mouseout', toggleIcon);
```

```css
.icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.active {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon"></div>
```